# Calling an MVC controller / action in an external assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am trying to call a controller action defined in an external assembly but application always returns that the resource is not found. the controller is trivial and looks like this:

```
namespace MyExternal.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class ProjAdminController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I updated the route to include the optional namespace:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },         
  new[] { "MyExternal.Controllers" }
 );
```

However, when I try to invoke the controller and action it doesnt find the controller.  I installed the route debugger and it passes the route test , but it doesnt find the controller or stop on my breakpoint. Its probably someting pretty small, but I can't figure this out. My apologies is this is a dup. turns out the original code had a bug in the naming of the controller class, but the rest of the code works nicely as an example of how to do this.

Comment: is the external assembly in the bin folder? what is the URL you are trying?

Comment: Turns out this works fine as expected but could be a nice example of how to do it without resorting to a directly bound Area.  I had mistakenly not named my controller with the Controller suffix and it wouldnt find it by convention. sigh. however the namespaces spec in the route registration helps find the controller significantly faster than if you dont as the request handler can search these namespaces first ahead of the the more lenghtly search

Comment: Areas are not required for what you want, so I'm not sure what's the problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you should add `area` parameter to the action invocation. It should contains a namespace of that controller.

Comment: I can try this, but it really doesnt explain why this doesn't work or what the namespace parameter is doing if its not supposed to work this way

Comment: turns out my contoller is not named by convention and I couldn't spot the problem.